# Printing List with condition statement if-else in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the list with condition statement if-then-else, 
but instead of printing the whole list, it prints only the first List element.
It only prints 'Bit On'

```
<html>
<ul id="stt">
    <li>First</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>

<script>
var getIt = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var txt = "";
for (var i = 0; i < getIt.length; ++i){
    if (getIt.item(i).textContent !== null)
        document.getElementById("stt").innerHTML = "Bit On";
    else
        document.getElementById("stt").innerHTML = "Bit Off";
}   


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("stt").innerHTML =` ... overwrite the innerHTML value every time ... you'll end up with the appropriate value for the LAST `li`, not the FIRST ... try `.innerHTML += ...`

Comment: I am looking if the list has text then print 'Bit On' and if the list is empty then 'Bit Off'.

Comment: @user6642297 If those are your specs, then it works as expected, no? The list has text, so it prints "Bit On". The strict comparison to null will probably not work though, even if the list would be empty. Unclear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @user6642297 but you want to replace all the content in the ul ? because that's it what you doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing elements in an array-like object, better to use square brackets, like `[i]`. You need to assign to the items' `textContent`. You also need to select the `ul`'s *children* if you want to iterate through the list, not the `ul` itself:

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].children;
var txt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  if (lis[i].textContent)
    lis[i].textContent = "Bit On";
  else
    lis[i].textContent = "Bit Off";
}
```

```html
<ul id="stt">
  <li>First</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

But it would be better to select and iterate directly via querySelectorAll:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  if (li.textContent) li.textContent = "Bit On";
  else li.textContent = "Bit Off";
});
```

```html
<ul id="stt">
  <li>First</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```

The code is much cleaner.

Comment: @user6642297 if this solution works, consider accepting this answer as correct one by checking check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the  tag, of which there is only 1, and then
changing the element with with id *stt* again of which there is only 1. It's not clear exactly what you want to do, but I think this is it:

```
var getIt = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < getIt.length; i++){
    if (getIt.item(i).textContent.length === 0)
        getIt.item(i).innerHTML = "Bit On";
    else
        getIt.item(i).innerHTML = "Bit Off";
}
```

Comment: Arthur Musgrove, It also worked perfectly. Thank you and thanks also to @CertainPerfomance too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you are looping through the wrong element. `getIt` gets all elements with tag name `ul` and it's only one. Therefore it replaces the `ul` content with Bit On since it is not empty. You should loop through the elements with `li` tag.

```js
var getIt = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
//console.log(getIt);
for (var i = 0; i < getIt.length; ++i){
    if (getIt.item(i).textContent !== '')
        getIt.item(i).innerHTML = "Bit On";
    else
        getIt.item(i).innerHTML = "Bit Off";
}
```

```html
<ul id="stt">
    <li>First</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Fifth</li>
</ul>
```